# vswprintf fails for certain unicode codepoints under Mac OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, darwin

I am getting inexplicable failures (return value -1) from `vswprintf` using GCC and Mac OS X (tested with gcc 4.0 and 4.2.1 under Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.8. GCC under Linux is **not** affected. Visual Studio is also **not** affected).

To demonstrate the problem I have minimally adapted the example from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/vswprintf/) so that it prints out `vswprintf`'s return value:

```
/* vswprintf example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void PrintWide ( const wchar_t * format, ... )
{
    wchar_t buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start ( args, format );
    int res = vswprintf ( buffer, 256, format, args );
    wprintf ( L"result=%d\n", res );
    fputws ( buffer, stdout );
    va_end ( args );
}

int main ()
{
    wchar_t str[] = L"test string has %d wide characters.\n";
    PrintWide ( str, wcslen(str) );
    return 0;
}
```

From my tests it appears that, depending on the value of `str`,  `vswprintf` will sometimes fail. Examples:

```
wchar_t str[] = L"test string has %d wide characters.\n"; // works
wchar_t str[] = L"ßß® test string has %d wide characters.\n"; // works
wchar_t str[] = L"日本語 test string has %d wide characters.\n"; // FAILS
wchar_t str[] = L"Π test string has %d wide characters.\n"; // FAILS
wchar_t str[] = L"\u03A0 test string has %d wide characters.\n"; // FAILS
```

It appears that any strings that include characters with Unicode codepoints above `0xff` will trigger this problem. Can anyone shed some light into why this is happening? It seems like too big an issue to not have been noticed before!

Comment: Does the encoding of your source file match the encoding expected in the strings?

Comment: I'd expect the `fputws` call to fail in the default `"C"` locale for out-of-range characters, but the `vswprintf` should work.

Comment: There is no "GCC vswprintf" as the title says. The reason GCC on GNU/Linux behaves differently to GCC on Mac OS X is because `vswprintf` is nothing to do with GCC, it is provided by the OS's C library, `libc`

Comment: Thanks. I have amended the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the locale, it should be fine. To pick up the environment variable you can do this:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");   // include <locale.h>
```

or set it explicitly. This is because all of the output functions need to know which encoding to use.

OS X is failing to perform the `vswprintf` at all, while Linux runs it (though the characters will be incorrect if printed).

Here's the relevant section from the glibc documentation:

> ```
>    If  the  format  string contains non-ASCII wide characters, the program
>    will only work correctly if the LC_CTYPE category of the current locale
>    at  run time is the same as the LC_CTYPE category of the current locale
>    at compile time.  This is because the wchar_t representation  is  plat‐
>    form-  and  locale-dependent.   (The  glibc  represents wide characters
>    using their Unicode (ISO-10646) code point, but other  platforms  don't
>    do  this.
> ```

Comment: Actually, IMO the `vswprintf` call shouldn't be affected by the locale, but the `fputsw` call should fail...

Comment: You are indeed right! Incidentally, under Ubuntu 11.04 the call not only succeeds, but the output is correct even without setting the locale.

Comment: @Xaxx - glad it helped. I think Ubuntu 11.04 must be being more permissive. I tried in Ubuntu 12.10 and it gave the wrong chars (the man page says LC_CTYPE must be set).

Comment: @teppic - I should have been more precise. Under Ubuntu the `vswprintf` call succeeds and the result buffer is filled in with the correct codepoints. However, if you then try to print it out (e.g., using printf) then the output will not be correct unless LC_CTYPE is set.

Comment: @Xaxx - ah I see. I didn't check that in 12.10. But yes, on OS X the call just fails altogether, even with the ASCII.