# setlocale works in iOS Simulator but fails on device

Tags: ios, localization

Unlike the author of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555129/setlocale-doesnt-work-in-ios-simulator), I'm having the opposite problem.  I'm attempting to make use of a component written in C++ in my iPad application that uses setlocale() from the standard C library.  When running via the simulator (either i386 or x86_64), I'm able to set a locale successfully and get an expected return value:

```
(lldb) p (const char *)setlocale(2, "ja_JP")
(const char *) $1 = 0x000000010e776bd0 "ja_JP"
```

However, when running on a device (on either iOS8 or iOS9, on both armv7 and arm64 devices), this call always seems to fail and return null.

```
(lldb) p (const char *)setlocale(2, "ja_JP")
(const char *) $0 = 0x00000000
```

Actually setting the region and language on the iOS device doens't seem to make a difference either.

Is this an example of something like iOS9 preventing the use of sysctl(), or am I missing something bigger here?

Answer (score 2):

This was actually answered on the Apple Dev Forums recently, sharing it here as well:

> The problem here is not setlocale per se, but rather in reading the
>   locale in the first place.  Notably, newlocale also returns NULL when
>   you call it with similar parameters. This fails because no C-style
>   locales are available to you on iOS. On the simulator this works
>   because the locale code picks up the locale data from OS X (in
>   /usr/share/locale).  I’m not sure if this directory is populated on
>   iOS (I suspect not) but that doesn’t matter because the sandbox won’t
>   let your process get to it.